# Measurability of indicator of two hitting times at the stopped $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory, brownian-motion, stopping-times

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the complete filtration generated by the Brownian motion $B$, and let $a<0<b$. Define the stopping times
$\tau_a=\inf\{t\ge 0|B_t=a\}$ and $\tau_b=\inf\{t\ge 0|B_t=b\}$.
Then is the indicator
$1_{\tau_b<\tau_a}$  measurable with respect to
$\mathcal{F}_{\tau_b}$?

---

The claim holds if one of $\tau_a$ and $\tau_b$ is replaced by a deterministic time. Does the claim hold with the hitting times? Intuitively, if we know the history of $B$ up to the time once it first hits $b$, when should know whether it already hits $a$ or not, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We define $A_n$ as following and we see that
$$\begin{aligned}A_n:&=\{\tau_b +1/n>  \tau_a\}\cap\{\tau_b\leq t\}=\\
&= \bigcup_{q \in \mathbb{Q}}\{\tau_b+1/n> q\}\cap\{\tau_a\leq q\}\cap \{\tau_b\leq t\}=\\
&= \bigcup_{q \in \mathbb{Q},q< t+1/n}\{\tau_b+1/n\leq  q\}^c\cap\{\tau_a\leq q\}\cap \{\tau_b\leq t\}\in \mathscr{F}_{t+1/n}\\
\end{aligned}$$
and that $A_n\supseteq A_{n+1},\forall n$ and $\cap_nA_n=\{\tau_b\geq \tau_a\}\cap\{\tau_b\leq t\}$. Furthermore, we note $\cap_nA_n=\cap_{k\geq \ell}A_k\in \mathscr{F}_{t+1/\ell}$ for any $\ell \in \mathbb{N}$ since $\mathscr{F}_{t+1/k}\subseteq \mathscr{F}_{t+1/\ell},\forall k \geq \ell$. That is, $\cap_nA_n \in \mathscr{F}_{t+1/\ell},\,\forall \ell \in \mathbb{N}$. But then $\cap_nA_n \in \mathscr{F}_{t^+}=\cap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\mathscr{F}_{t+1/n}$. This finally implies
$$\{\tau_b\geq \tau_a\}\in \mathscr{F}_{\tau_b^+}:=\{A\in \mathscr{F}_\infty:A\cap \{\tau_b\leq t\}\in \mathscr{F}_{t^+}\}$$
However, if $(\mathscr{F}_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is assumed to be a right-continuous filtration (i.e. $\mathscr{F}_{t^+}=\mathscr{F}_t,\forall t\geq 0$) then $\{\tau_b\geq \tau_a\}\in \mathscr{F}_{\tau_b}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this shows $\{\tau_b\ge \tau_a\}$ is measurable at the larger stopping time. Do you think whether it is measurable at the smaller stopping time (as in the question)?

Comment: @John $\mathscr{F}_{\tau_b^+}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. So $\{\tau_b<\tau_a\}=\{\tau_b\geq \tau_a\}^c\in\mathscr{F}_{\tau_b^+}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing this out. I will read your answer carefully to make sure I fully understand it. After that, I will then accept it.

Comment: @John please do feel free to ask for more details and if you think something is unclear

Answer (score 0):

The process $X_t:=1_{\{t<\tau_a\}}$ is $(\mathcal F_t)$-adapted (because $\tau_a$ is a stopping time) and right continuous. It is therefore $(\mathcal F_t)$-optional. Consequently the r.v. $X_{\tau_b}$, which coincides with $1_{\{\tau_b<\tau_a\}}$, is $\mathcal F_{\tau_b}$-measurable.